# C# Short , Byte Takes 4 Byte in x86

Tags: c#, memory, short

This is the code i use in x86 and x64

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        short a = 4;




        short b = 5;


        short* x = &a;
        short* y = &b;

        Console.WriteLine((int)x);
        Console.WriteLine((int)y);


        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

for x86 i am getting answer like " xxxxx224  xxxxx220"
for x64 i am getting answer like " xxxxx000  xxxxx002"

Why is the Short , Byte , Bool Taking 4 bytes in x86 and Normal on x64

Comment: You're not even guaranteed to get the same class layout. AFAIK the JIT si free to choose whatever it pleases here. Alignment concerns exist on one side, size constraints on another. Also the 32-bit JIT and the 64-bit JIT are completely separate pieces of code. They don't have to work the same.

Comment: Furthermore, what do you gain from an answer here? If you care about memory layout, there are better ways to control it, e.g. with attributes for struct members. If you don't, then why bother?

Comment: I am trying to learn how things works with this . i couldnt solve why 32 bit JIT does this and 64 Bit JIT reacts in different way .  Is there any specific reason behind this

Answer (score 1):

That is the memory address of the short values that you are outputting. You are getting 32-bit values as presumably your program is compiled as a 32-bit application.

Comment: Yes , thats the memory address . so its allocating 4 byte for a short in 32 bit and 2 bytes in 64 bit ?

Comment: No, it will be using 4 bytes in all of your cases - unless you were to compile to run on 64-bit. Just running on an x64 processor won't make any difference to how much memory is allocated, it will still be running under a 32-bit emulator ("WOW64").

Comment: Yes sir , but why compile to run on 64-bit allocates 2 Bytes for short and 4 Bytes while compile to run 32-bit. what link i am missing . i couldn't figure it out

Comment: I don't think that it is only using 2 bytes under 64-bit, it's just that the addresses happen to be lower. As @Joey says, the runtime picks how to allocate memory and there appears to be some difference between the way the 32 and 64 processor implementations choose to allocate. Have you tried allocating a large array in the same class for instance? You might be able to prove what I said if you can get the shorts to be placed at a higher address.